# Error in Michael Hartl Rails Tutorial Chapter 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get the test to work for signup and account activation. It looks like there's an error in the template which tries to create a route using a method. Here is the error:

```
ERROR["test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation", UsersSignupTest, 1.614055]
 test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation#UsersSignupTest (1.61s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"user@example.com", :format=>nil, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

The template creates the route with:

```
<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, 
                                                    email: @user.email) %>
```

I am using resources in the routing so you would think this would produce the correct route. Here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                'static_pages#home'
  get    'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get    'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
end
```

The error says it's missing an id, which to me would mean it needs the record to be inserted into the database (and thus an id generated) before accessing the route. But the error occurs after the save on the line **@user.send_activation_email**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

With the user class defining the send_activation_email method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor   :remember_token, :activation_token
    before_save     :downcase_email
  before_create   :create_activation_digest

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end
```

Finally, the account activations controller does have an edit function, so the route should be found by the app. In the book, the edit function has not yet been implemented and it is still suppose to work... I went ahead and implemented the edit function anyways:

```
class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.update_attribute(:activated,    true)
      user.update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

So I guess the question is, why isn't this id generated?

Finally, the test that generates the error:

```
test "valid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post_via_redirect users_path, user: { name:  "Example User",
                                            email: "user@example.com",
                                            password:              "password",
                                            password_confirmation: "password" }
    end
    # assert_template 'users/show'
    # assert is_logged_in?
  end
```

Comment: Sounds like activation_token is nil.

Comment: I have the same problem, could you solve it? Also in my case the edit_account_activation[s]_url is working, notice the s, without that the compiler says no such method

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem going through the tutorial.  I'm posting this incase anybody else runs into the problem.  The problem was in the user model where I was not creating the activation_token.  If anybody runs into the problem try to make sure that you are creating the activation_token in the User model with the before_create :create_activation_digest call.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.  What happened to me was I deleted the self from:

```
def create_activation_digest
self.activation_token = User.new_token
self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
end
```

I don't exactly remember why I did this, but adding the self. back in fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are no errors in tutorial, and it's difficult to understand what's wrong with your app, but if it may help, look at mine https://bitbucket.org/juliausanova/sample_app/src.
Maybe you will find the bug after comparing.
Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with an error message of:

> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template account_activations/edit, application edit with {#A BUNCH OF INFO}

In the ~/app/controllers/account_activations_controller.rb I forgot to add:

> redirect_to user

at the end of

`def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.update_attribute(:activated, true)
      user.update_attribute(:activated, Time.zone.now)
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
      redirect_to user`

Answer (score 0):

Going through the tutorial a little while later :D

I had a very similar error and the comment from @mtmcgurn to check the user model helped!

When changing the `authenticated?` method to work for remember and activation I hadn't removed the "remember_" from every line!